# why im getting this error in my code function returned null?

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

Why my widget give this error ?:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<UserData>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<UserData, AsyncSnapshot<UserData>>#1e46f):
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<UserData>
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<UserData> file:///Users/name/StudioProjects/project/lib/seitenleiste/meinacount.dart:356:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:305:7)
#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:326:4)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4592:7)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4759:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4281:5)
...
====================================================================================================
```

This is my widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<Userr>(context);
        return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
          stream: DatbaseService(uid:user.uid).userData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              UserData userData =snapshot.data;
              return Container(
                child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                  ),
                  body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
                    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 40.0,
                                  vertical: 10,
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Center(
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 110,
                                            height: 110,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                                      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3307758/pexels-photo-3307758.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250",
                                                    ))),
                                          ),
                                          Positioned(
                                              bottom: 0,
                                              right: 0,
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 35,
                                                width: 35,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                    width: 4,
                                                    color: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                                                  ),
                                                  color: Colors.green,
                                                ),
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  Icons.edit,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Mein Profil',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    showAlert2(),

                                      _buildEmailTF(userData),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                    _buildName(userData ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                    _builduserName(userData),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                    _buildPasswordTF(userData),
                                    SizedBox(height: 30,),

                                    _buildPassword2TF(userData),
                                    _buildUpdateDataButton(),
                                    // _buildEmailform(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              );

            }else{
              return null;
            }

          }
        );


      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite straightforward:

```
The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<UserData>
Build functions must never return null.
```

In your `StreamBuilder`, you are returning `null` if the `snapshot` has no data:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
  return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
    stream: DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        ...
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

The error message is providing the solution here:

```
To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill 
available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space 
that takes as little room as possible, 
return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
```

So, instead of returning `null`, just return an empty `Container`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
  return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
    stream: DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Props for this extensive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error message:

> A build function returned null.
>
> The offending widget is: StreamBuilder
> Build functions must never return null.
>
> To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

You’re returning null in your else